# how create clean urls using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Hi i want to create clean urls but my htaccess file does not create any effect.

Original url - http://example.com/abc/def/?page=1

required url - http://example.com/abc/def/page/1

I am using following htaccess file. I want to place this file in the def directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ page?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `def` is indeed a directory, use the following inside it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+?)/?\?(page)=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/page/(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(page)/(\d+)/?$ /%1/?page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: After changing rewirte to rewrite in above code it is giving 500 internal server error

Comment: It is redirecting to following url

Comment: @Alex Ah, In the first rewriterule above, try: `RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]`